# Related data with a range

Tags: sql, oracle, range, listagg

I have a table ITEMS with an id and non unique items

```
ID  ITEM
1   banana
1   apple
2   pear
2   grapes
3   carrots
4   parsnips
5   hats
6   scarves
```

Is it possible to write a query that returns all combination of a from-id and a to-id and the distinct list of items from each, including a null to-id

This will bring me back all the from-id and to-id combinations

```
with q as (
select rownum as id
from dual 
connect by level <= (select max(id) from items)
union select null as id from dual  )

select q1.id as id1, q2.id as id2
from q q1
cross join q q2
where q1.id is not null
and (q1.id < q2.id or q2.id is null)

order by q1.id, q2.id


   ID1        ID2
     1          2
     1          3
     1          4
     1          5
     1          6
     1           
     2          3
     2          4
     2          5
     2          6
     2
```

I can then use this to trivially retreive the items,

```
with q as (
select rownum as id
from dual 
connect by level <= (select max(id) from items)
union select null as id from dual  )

select q1.id as id1, q2.id as id2, listagg(i.item,',') within group (order by i.item) as item_list
from q q1
cross join q q2
left join ITEMS i on (i.id = q1.id or i.id = q2.id)
where q1.id is not null
and (q1.id < q2.id or q2.id is null)
group by q1.id, q2.id;
order by q1.id, q2.id


ITEM_LIST                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

         1             apple,banana                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

         1          2  apple,banana,grapes,pear                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

         1          3  apple,banana,carrots  
;
```

However its not right as it not bring back the in-between numbers, so
1 3 should be apple,banana,grapes,pear,carrots

1 and null, should be bring back the full list of items

I can obviously do it in pl/sql but wondered if can be done in a single SQL statment

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, IMHO you should have added one more join with `between` expression to get final data from your pairs. And for number-to-null pairs, it is good to treat null as max value (or infinity). My attempt:

```
with items (ID,  ITEM) as (
select 1, 'banana' from dual union all
select 1, 'apple' from dual union all
select 2, 'pear' from dual union all
select 2, 'grapes' from dual union all
select 3, 'carrots' from dual union all
select 4, 'parsnips' from dual union all
select 5, 'hats' from dual union all
select 6, 'scarves' from dual
)
, all_pairs (id_from, id_to) as (
  select distinct t1.id, t2.id
  from items t1
  join (
    select distinct id from items
    union
    (select max(id) + 1 from items)
  ) t2 on t1.id < t2.id
)
--select * from all_pairs order by id_from, id_to
select p.id_from, nullif(p.id_to, (select max(id) + 1 from items)) as id_to
     , listagg(t.item, ',') within group (order by t.id, t.item) as item_list
from all_pairs p
join items t on t.id between p.id_from and p.id_to
group by p.id_from, p.id_to
order by 1, 2 nulls first
```

| ID_FROM | ID_TO | ITEM_LIST |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | *null* | apple,banana,grapes,pear,carrots,parsnips,hats,scarves |
| 1 | 2 | apple,banana,grapes,pear |
| 1 | 3 | apple,banana,grapes,pear,carrots |
| 1 | 4 | apple,banana,grapes,pear,carrots,parsnips |
| 1 | 5 | apple,banana,grapes,pear,carrots,parsnips,hats |
| 1 | 6 | apple,banana,grapes,pear,carrots,parsnips,hats,scarves |
| 2 | *null* | grapes,pear,carrots,parsnips,hats,scarves |
| 2 | 3 | grapes,pear,carrots |
| 2 | 4 | grapes,pear,carrots,parsnips |
| 2 | 5 | grapes,pear,carrots,parsnips,hats |
| 2 | 6 | grapes,pear,carrots,parsnips,hats,scarves |
| 3 | *null* | carrots,parsnips,hats,scarves |
| 3 | 4 | carrots,parsnips |
| 3 | 5 | carrots,parsnips,hats |
| 3 | 6 | carrots,parsnips,hats,scarves |
| 4 | *null* | parsnips,hats,scarves |
| 4 | 5 | parsnips,hats |
| 4 | 6 | parsnips,hats,scarves |
| 5 | *null* | hats,scarves |
| 5 | 6 | hats,scarves |
| 6 | *null* | scarves |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UWVUAxEv)

Comment: The usage of between join condition is excellent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hierarchical query and `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH` to generate the path:

```sql
WITH items (id, items) AS (
  -- Concatenate the items at the same level
  SELECT id,
         LISTAGG(item, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY item)
  FROM   table_name
  GROUP BY id
),
paths (from_id, to_id, items, is_leaf) AS (
  -- Generate the paths
  SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT id,
         id,
         SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(items, ';'),
         CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF
  FROM   items
  CONNECT BY PRIOR id + 1 = id
)
SELECT from_id,
       to_id,
       REPLACE(SUBSTR(items, 2), ';', ',') AS items
FROM   paths
UNION ALL
-- Add the null values
SELECT from_id,
       NULL,
       REPLACE(SUBSTR(items, 2), ';', ',')
FROM   paths
WHERE  is_leaf = 1;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID, ITEM) AS
SELECT 1, 'banana'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'apple'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'pear'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'grapes'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'carrots'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'parsnips' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'hats'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'scarves'  FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| FROM_ID | TO_ID | ITEMS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | apple,banana |
| 1 | 2 | apple,banana,grapes,pear |
| 1 | 3 | apple,banana,grapes,pear,carrots |
| 1 | 4 | apple,banana,grapes,pear,carrots,parsnips |
| 1 | 5 | apple,banana,grapes,pear,carrots,parsnips,hats |
| 1 | 6 | apple,banana,grapes,pear,carrots,parsnips,hats,scarves |
| 2 | 2 | grapes,pear |
| 2 | 3 | grapes,pear,carrots |
| 2 | 4 | grapes,pear,carrots,parsnips |
| 2 | 5 | grapes,pear,carrots,parsnips,hats |
| 2 | 6 | grapes,pear,carrots,parsnips,hats,scarves |
| 3 | 3 | carrots |
| 3 | 4 | carrots,parsnips |
| 3 | 5 | carrots,parsnips,hats |
| 3 | 6 | carrots,parsnips,hats,scarves |
| 4 | 4 | parsnips |
| 4 | 5 | parsnips,hats |
| 4 | 6 | parsnips,hats,scarves |
| 5 | 5 | hats |
| 5 | 6 | hats,scarves |
| 6 | 6 | scarves |
| 1 | *null* | apple,banana,grapes,pear,carrots,parsnips,hats,scarves |
| 2 | *null* | grapes,pear,carrots,parsnips,hats,scarves |
| 3 | *null* | carrots,parsnips,hats,scarves |
| 4 | *null* | parsnips,hats,scarves |
| 5 | *null* | hats,scarves |
| 6 | *null* | scarves |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QIg41xit)

Answer (score 0):

Try it like below:

```sql
WITH      --  S a m p l e   d a t a 
    tbl (ID, ITEM) AS
        (
            Select 1, 'banana'    From Dual Union All
            Select 1, 'apple'     From Dual Union All
            Select 2, 'pear'      From Dual Union All
            Select 2, 'grapes'    From Dual Union All
            Select 3, 'carrots'   From Dual Union All
            Select 4, 'parsnips'  From Dual Union All
            Select 5, 'hats'      From Dual Union All
            Select 6, 'scarves'   From Dual 
        )
--  M a i n   S Q L
SELECT  DISTINCT a.FROM_ID, a.TO_ID, 
        ( Select LISTAGG(ITEM, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (Order By ID, ITEM) From tbl Where ID Between a.FROM_ID And a.TO_ID)  "LIST_ITEMS"
FROM    ( Select      l.LVL "FROM_ID", t.ID "TO_ID"
          From        tbl t
          Inner Join  ( Select LEVEL "LVL" From dual Connect By LEVEL <= 6 ) l ON(1=1)
          Where       l.LVL <= t.ID
          Group By    l.LVL, t.ID
          Order By    l.LVL, t.ID
        ) a
Order By  FROM_ID, TO_ID

--  R e s u l t
   FROM_ID      TO_ID LIST_ITEMS                                                        
---------- ---------- ------------------------------------------------------------------
         1          1 apple, banana                                                     
         1          2 apple, banana, grapes, pear                                       
         1          3 apple, banana, grapes, pear, carrots                              
         1          4 apple, banana, grapes, pear, carrots, parsnips                    
         1          5 apple, banana, grapes, pear, carrots, parsnips, hats              
         1          6 apple, banana, grapes, pear, carrots, parsnips, hats, scarves     
         2          2 grapes, pear                                                      
         2          3 grapes, pear, carrots                                             
         2          4 grapes, pear, carrots, parsnips                                   
         2          5 grapes, pear, carrots, parsnips, hats                             
         2          6 grapes, pear, carrots, parsnips, hats, scarves                    
         3          3 carrots                                                           
         3          4 carrots, parsnips                                                 
         3          5 carrots, parsnips, hats                                           
         3          6 carrots, parsnips, hats, scarves                                  
         4          4 parsnips                                                          
         4          5 parsnips, hats                                                    
         4          6 parsnips, hats, scarves                                           
         5          5 hats                                                              
         5          6 hats, scarves                                                     
         6          6 scarves
```